# How to get PyDev to work with MathPlotLib?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, matplotlib, pydev

Whenever I run this code, a window pops up and immediately disappears. The Python interpreter is setup and all other commands work both in the console and in the editor. I am currently using Eclipse 2019 and Python 2.7.

Changing the last line of my code from fig.show() to PLT.show() works for only this program (I need a more robust solution). I have installed the PyQt4 library into Eclipse/PyDev just in case.

```
'''
Read and show an image.
'''
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
import numpy as np # "as" lets us use standard abbreviations
#from PyQt4.Qt import QEventLoop

'''Read the image data'''
# Get the directory of this python script
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
# Build an absolute filename from directory + filename
filename = os.path.join(directory, 'woman.jpg')
# Read the image data into an array
img = plt.imread(filename)

'''Show the image data'''
# Create figure with 1 subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# Show the image data in a subplot
ax.imshow(img, interpolation='none')

# Show the figure on the screen
fig.show() #changed from fig.show()
```

There are no error messages, but the window does not stay long enough.

Comment: `fig.show()` requires an event loop running. Use `plt.show()` instead.

Comment: I've gotten that to work. I guess I'll just need to ask questions about each program. Thanks!